Angular get data from clipboard
im using bellow function to get copied data from clipboard
onPasteData(section:string){
navigator.clipboard.readText().then(s => 
  input = s
); 
}

s holding bellow data line by line with line break before the last line
Tony
USA

addtionline3

onPastData in a click function. what im try to do is move this data into array
expected array
let finalArray = [{ "Name" : Tony,
                     "Country" : USA,
                    "Additional" : addtionline3
                   }]

i tried using split but enable to get the result
const lines = input.split(/\r?\n/).filter(line => line.trim() !== '');


We can use shift array method to pop the first element from the array, and then push the remaining lines to Additional.


const input = `Tony
input

addtionline3`;

const lines = input.split(/\r?\n/).filter(line => line.trim() !== '');

const output = lines.length >= 2 ? [{
  Name: lines.shift(),
  Country: lines.shift(),
  Additional: lines,
}] : [];

console.log(output);




Here's a solution that should work:
function onPasteData(section: string) {
  navigator.clipboard.readText().then(input => {
    // Split the input by line breaks and remove empty lines
    const lines = input.split(/\r?\n/).filter(line => line.trim() !== '');

    // Create the object with the parsed data
    const parsedData = {
      Name: lines[0] || '',
      Country: lines[1] || '',
      Additional: lines[2] || ''
    };

    // Create the final array with the parsed object
    const finalArray = [parsedData];

    console.log(finalArray);
    // You can now use finalArray as needed
  });
}

This code does the following:

We use navigator.clipboard.readText() to get the clipboard content.
We split the input string by line breaks and remove any empty lines using split(/\r?\n/) and filter().
We create an object parsedData with the desired structure, assigning values from the lines array to the corresponding keys.
We create finalArray by wrapping parsedData in an array.

The resulting finalArray will have the structure you're looking for:
let finalArray = [{
  "Name": "Tony",
  "Country": "USA",
  "Additional": "addtionline3"
}]

This approach is more robust as it handles cases where some lines might be missing. If a line is missing, the corresponding value in the object will be an empty string.
